# Enable Compatibility View AKA IE7 mode in Edge in Windows 11

Tags: microsoft-edge, internet-explorer-11, internet-explorer-7

An [Indian Government website](https://icegate.gov.in/Download/JavaSetupForDSC.pdf) requires ***IE7 Compatibility View*** to upload a digital signature [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FW6P2.png) !! In Windows 11 Edge how do I create such a view? Internet Explorer mode of Edge does not work in this webpage.

---

Edit:
[This is the problematic page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4VHU.jpg). To access it Go To [icegate.gov.in](https://icegate.gov.in) *> User Login/Signup > Sign up now > enter dummy details > check availability > User Role > others* now you get into the problem.

Comment: IE 7 went out of support 6 years ago. All versions of IE will go out of support this year & will be forcibly uninstalled from current systems. Someone needs to get their finger out.

Comment: Yeah. Subjecting its citizens to risk by using outdated technology.

Comment: I noticed the pdf is talking about Java 8 too. tbh, I'd write to them & say "I cannot comply with your request because the technology employed is no longer supported by any current computer." [Note, the UK govt isn't exactly standards-compliant either; this is not just an India issue, it's a govt everywhere issue;) Case in point, some govt web sign-ins cannot be remembered by my secure keychain, but the [insecure] auto-fill will remember it - which is truly hideous security compliance.

Comment: I don't think you can download IE 7.  Even to use true IE 11 you would need a virtual machine to do that. Even so, my Windows 7 machine updated IE 11 to Edge for Windows 7.  So you will have significant trouble trying to accomplish what you want.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Edge, in IE Mode, uses iexplore.exe in the background to render the page. Therefore, IE is available in Windows 11. You can run IE on Windows 11 via a simple three line script. Then you have your choice of just using IE with that old site or set the Compatibility View in IE so that it works in Edge in IE Mode. Here's the script (save this as a text file with a .VBS extension, such as LaunchIE.vbs):

```
Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
oIE.Visible = True
oIE.Navigate "about:blank" 'put your URL of choice here
```

Comment: OK Windows 11 build 22000.348 is required for this? Rather M$ could add a IE7 compatibility view directly in that Default Browser setting. The IT industry history is full of blunders where companies ditch their install base in the name of innovation only to see themselves get shot in the foot. e.g VB6 PS: This is not an old site. It is a most happening Indian Government SIte with thousands of transactions - relying on Java and  IE7!! A sitting duck...

Comment: Yes, Windows 11 build 22000.348 or higher is required. IE COM is broken prior to that version.

Comment: Yep. It works fine even from Edge. Now for M$ to give a more direct option, else ordinary users will remain at windows 10. Nevertheless, I appreciate this kindness from M$ in not sacrificing old technology and those businesses dependent on it.

Comment: Nearly 6 million hits received in the Indian website icegate.gov.in and for them to use DSC in windows 11 your solution is the only hope. Realizing this market size M$ will surely give a direct settings. You are on the way to fame. Ignore the down votes. They are the bad strategists.

Comment: It doesn't really matter who or how many are affected. Correct answers should not be down-voted. If they think there is an error in the answer, they should point it out.

Comment: Reason for the down votes is: Prior to Build 22000.348 there was not way to bring up IE. Some celebrated this as the final death knell of IE, not aware that it was BUG by M$. Now on seeing IE back to life, they are ventilating with negative votes.... I just now completed an automation of filling hundreds of fields in a [webpage](https://imports.gov.in/MEITY/public/home) from Excel. IE and VBA rocks.

Comment: This isn't a popularity contest. It's simply a matter of what's factual. Stackoverflow has a good reputation for sticking to the facts. On the topic of IE in Windows 11, the facts are pretty messed up in much of the tech media and that has carried over into tech support sites.

Comment: @RaviGanesh - "Reason for the down votes is: Prior to Build 22000.348 there was not way to bring up IE." - The downvotes have more to do with the fact the question, the way it's currently worded, makes it appear that website will only work with IE7.  In reality the website only requires IE11.

Comment: These two nomenclatures shows paucity of imagination by M$ Engineers: 1. IE Compatibility Mode in Edge 2. Compatibility View in IE11 (I would call it IE7 compatibility mode)

Comment: After an automatic windows update, this script no more works! It opens an empty window. Entering a valid URL open Edge. What a mess! I was using Excel and VBA to automate a website. Suddenly it is all down the drain. Why M$.

Comment: Maybe a policy was pushed to you computer that disables VBScript? Try [this exe](https://lesferch.github.io/LaunchIE/)

Comment: Hurray. 4 ways to stop Internet Explorer from opening Edge solved my problem. (Method 2 worked first shot) https://www.guidingtech.com/stop-internet-explorer-from-opening-edge/

Comment: I tried your .exe (have full trust in you ;-) I am afraid it does not work. So need to disable the redirects to Edge.

Comment: @RaviGanesh It seems there is some issue with the COM (or at least the IE COM object) on your computer. That was an issue in Windows 11 a long time ago, prior to Build 22000.348. That should not be an issue now. I tested on Release Preview, Dev, and Canary builds (with all updates applied) and still had no problem using the script or the exe. Maybe try a [repair install](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/repair-install-windows-11-with-an-in-place-upgrade.418/).

Answer (score 0):

IE7 mode does not exist in Microsoft Edge.

The best solution is to create a Windows XP virtual machine and use it
to access that website.

See for example the article
[How to Set Up a Windows XP Virtual Machine for Free](https://helpdeskgeek.com/virtualization/how-to-set-up-a-windows-xp-virtual-machine-for-free/).

Comment: Ultimately I will have to access my Digital Certificate key in a USB Crypto dongle sitting in my host computer.... Hmm, hope that is do able.

Comment: Contact a government official and tell them you need access but are not able to do so. Point them to this page that lets them know, a lot of citizens of India will have a problem soon. IE has reached end of life status and its dangarous to use. SuperUser will simply not help people do terrible things to their computers. Ask them what you can do to get that certificate to work for Google Chrome. Maybe that is already possible, and maybe it even works in Edge browser too.

Comment: Thankyou. I mailed Utkarsh.KumarShuklaINFOSYS@icegate.gov.in. And I keep praying to get a reply!! BTW I understand it uses java and activeX and hence works in IE7 compatibility view settings only - and may be Netscape ;-)

Comment: I have tried your website in IE11 in compatibility mode and it seems to work. Have you followed the instructions about setting *Tools >  Compatibility view setting* and clicking Add? Have you installed Java?

Comment: Go To [icegate.gov.in](https://www.icegate.gov.in/) > _User Login/Signup > Sign up now > enter dummy details > check availability > User Role > others_ now you get into the real devil with the Digital Certificate.

Comment: I don't think I'll register on this site. A Windows XP VM stays perhaps as the best option.

Comment: Oh not really required to register. With dummy details you can go up to the registration page. Now you can access to the link to the [DSC field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4VHU.jpg). Kindly inspect that let me know your valuable view.

Comment: Sorry, it asks me to give an ID photo and other details.

Comment: Compatibility View can be set. See [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1726655/1283806).

Comment: I literally have IE7 compatibility mode active on my computer. It says "Compatibility Mode: IE7". This answer is incorrect.

Comment: @Strill: This mode is very partial - many features do not exist, in spite of the name.

Comment: @harrymc If you add a page to IE's Compatibility View list (and you can still do that in Windows 11, as per my answer), then it renders in Edge IE Mode exactly as it does in IE because, well, it's actually being rendered by IE. No difference. That should suffice. It certainly works fine for the site listed by the OP. There's no need to go firing up a Windows XP VM.

Comment: It being partial is irrelevant to IE7 Document Mode existing. It can go as low as IE5.

Answer (score -1):

> An Windows 11 Edge how do I create such a view?

Since Windows 11 only supports Microsoft Edge. Additionally, IE11 cannot run on Windows 11, and IE compatibility mode that exists within Microsoft Edge only supports IE11 not IE7.  **All this means is that what you want is impossible to achieve with Microsoft Edge on Windows 11.**

> Internet Explorer mode of Edge does not work in this webpage.

You will have to use a virtual machine which runs an operating system that supports IE11 which supports the compatibility mode you seek.

Comment: Edge is absolutely supported on Windows 10. Additionally, you can go as low as IE5 Document Mode.

Comment: @TylerMontney - Please read the author's question.  Please read my answer to that question.  **My answer states does not state that Edge is not supported by Windows 10.**

Comment: Ah, the way it was worded threw me off, on top of being other places that claimed Edge only worked on 11.

Comment: @TylerMontney - What part of my answer "threw you off" exactly because I only have 4 sentences.

Comment: I would like to confirm and acknowledge that IE (including the badly sought IE7 mode) is fully supported  in Windows 11 using LesFerch's hack.